# Power BI DAX formula doesn't work as expected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to develop DAX formula that calculates revenue of new customers.
New customers are calculated so: Revenue for current (selected) period is greater or equal to 0.01 and revenue for previous period is less than 0.01 or greater than -0.01.
There is slicer with values: current period, previous, Nov-23 and etc. But current revenue needs to be calculated for 12 rolling months, starting from last date of the selected period (if selected previous period, it is 31.12.2023). For revenue of previous period it is respectively 1.01.2022 - 31.12.2022 (12 rolling months)
I developed this formula:

```
Revenue = 
VAR _CurrentPeriodEnd =
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( 'Time'[Month] ) = TRUE (),
        MAX ( 'Time'[Day] )
    )
VAR _CurrentPeriodBegin =
    EDATE ( _CurrentPeriodEnd, -12 ) + 1
VAR _PreviousPeriodEnd =
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( 'Time'[Month] ) = TRUE (),
        EDATE ( _CurrentPeriodEnd, -12 ),
        EDATE ( _CurrentPeriodEnd, -12 )
    )
VAR _PreviousPeriodBegin =
    EDATE ( _PreviousPeriodEnd, -12 ) + 1
VAR _tblRevenue =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( 'Customers'[Customer] ),
        "FilterCP",
            CALCULATE (
                [Revenues],
                'Time'[Day] >= _CurrentPeriodBegin,
                'Time'[Day] <= _CurrentPeriodEnd
            ),
        "FilterPP",
            CALCULATE (
                [Revenues],
                'Time'[Day] >= _PreviousPeriodBegin,
                'Time'[Day] <= _PreviousPeriodEnd
            )
    )
VAR _tblPYRevenueBelowZero =
   CALCULATE(SUMX(_tblRevenue, [FilterCP]), FILTER(_tblRevenue, [FilterCP] >= 0.01 && [FilterPP]<0.01 && [FilterPP]>-0.01))
RETURN
    _tblPYRevenueBelowZero
```

I expect it to show revenue for current period of new customers, but it doesn't work. Separately, it is calculating revenue for previous 12 rolling months and current correctly, but this comparison (e.g. FilterCP>=0.01) doesn't work, it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
VAR _tblPYRevenueBelowZero =
  SUMX(
    _tblRevenue,
      var cp = CALCULATE([FilterCP])
      var pp = CALCULATE([FilterPP])
      return IF(cp >= 0.01 && pp < 0.01 && pp > -0.01, [FilterCP])
      // or return IF(cp >= 0.01 && pp < 0.01 && pp > -0.01, cp)
  )
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. I feel that it sums up all revenues before filtering, that's why I get huge number. It just sums up everything that has FilterCP >= 0.01, not taking into account FilterPP. But it needs to check row by row two columns and if all conditions are met (FilterCP >= 0.01, FilterPP < 0.01 & FilterPP > -0.01) - then return revenue for current period and summarize it.

Comment: I see, try this updated answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it doesn't allow to use variables in variables aka nested variables.

Comment: It works for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4N5l.png, share a screen grab of the error or double check the syntax.